# nested properties error on string with string

Tags: c#, .net, string, properties

I have 2 questions

1. Is there a way to initialize a class and all subclasses so all elements of the new item in the code are null?
2. How do I handle a list of type Items. EmbeddedGenerator  and stop the error

   ```
    Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
      at ConsoleApplication1.Program.SetProperty(String compoundProperty,
      Object target, String value)
      at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
      String[] args)
      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
      Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
      (ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback,
       Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
      executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   ```

   (new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView(((System.Collections.Generic.List)(target)))).Items[0].id.id_high

Example "class1.properity1 = 1"

I have run into an error here is a short console app outlining  what the error is 
I'm trying to set the value of id_high to 1 the path is generator.contents[0].id.id_high

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Items;
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
     class Program
     {
      static List<SavedItem> items = new List<SavedItem>();
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       Items.SavedItem item = new Items.SavedItem();
       item.generator = new Items.Generator();
       item.generator.contents = new List<Items.EmbeddedGenerator>();
       item.generator.contents.Add(new Items.EmbeddedGenerator());
       item.generator.contents[0].id = new OnlineService.ItemId();

       SetProperty(".generator.contents[0].id.id_high", item, "1");

       items.Add(item);
      }

      //jon skeet's modified method
      public static void SetProperty(string compoundProperty, 
      object target, string value)
      {
       string[] bits = compoundProperty.Split('.');
       for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length - 1; i++)
       {
        if (bits[i].IndexOf('[') > 0)
        {
         bits[i] = bits[i].Substring(0, bits[i].IndexOf('['));
        }

        PropertyInfo propertyToGet = target.GetType().GetProperty(bits[i]);
        target = propertyToGet.GetValue(target, null); 
       }
       if (bits[bits.Length - 1].IndexOf('[') > 0)
       {
        bits[bits.Length - 1] = bits[bits.Length - 1].Substring
        (0, bits[bits.Length - 1].IndexOf('['));
        value = value.Trim('{', '}');

        PropertyInfo lstpropertyToSet = target.GetType().GetProperty(bits.Last());
        if (value != "null")
        {

         List<int> list = new List<int>();
         foreach (string s in value.Split(','))
         {
          list.Add(Int32.Parse(s));
         }
         lstpropertyToSet.SetValue(target, 
          Convert.ChangeType(list, lstpropertyToSet.PropertyType)
          , null);
        }

        return;
       }
       PropertyInfo propertyToSet = target.GetType().GetProperty(bits.Last());
       if (value != "null")
       {
        propertyToSet.SetValue(target,
         Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyToSet.PropertyType),
         null);
       }
       return;
      }

     }
    }


   //....Items has an id_high separate from program   
    namespace Items
    {
     public partial class SavedItem
     {
      public SavedItem() { }
      private Items.Generator _generator = null;
      [global::System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(null)]
      public Items.Generator generator
      {
       get { return _generator; }
       set { _generator = value; }
      }
      //....
     }
     public partial class Generator 
     {
      public Generator() { }
      private System.Collections.Generic.List<EmbeddedGenerator> _contents = 
       new System.Collections.Generic.List<EmbeddedGenerator>();
      public System.Collections.Generic.List<EmbeddedGenerator> contents
      {
       get { return _contents; }
       set { _contents = value; }
      }
      //.....
     }
     public partial class EmbeddedGenerator
     {
      public EmbeddedGenerator() { }

      private OnlineService.ItemId _id;
      public OnlineService.ItemId id
      {
       get { return _id; }
       set { _id = value; }
      }
      //....
     }
    }
    //....onlineService has an id_high separate from ConsoleApplication1 and Items
    namespace OnlineService
    {
     public partial class ItemId 
     {
      public ItemId() { }

      private ulong _id_high;
      public ulong id_high
      {
       get { return _id_high; }
       set { _id_high = value; }
      }
     }
     //....
    }
```

This code will run normally until it gets to the contents collection answering the first question might solve my problem but I don't think it will because not all properties need a value and will cause issues if there is one.

Edit:
Adding this helped add  the property to the target 
But now "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"
 When you try to make target see item 1

item.generator.contents.Add(new Items.EmbeddedGenerator());
        item.generator.contents[0].id = new OnlineService.ItemId();

Comment: is there a way to expose all elements of a new object? Make it public. And what is your second question? Really can't understand what you mean.

Comment: it is public and i edited for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

1. Make the properties public.
2. error is because the property name in "bits[i]" does not exists in
   the target. You are  providing wrong property name. Pass the valid
   property and it will work.

   ```
   PropertyInfo propertyToGet = target.GetType().GetProperty(bits[i]);

   // bits[i] property doesnot exists in target.

   target = propertyToGet.GetValue(target, null); //here is the issues
   ```

Comment: the properties are public the property dose exist you can access it manually using  item.generator.contents[0].id.id_high = 1;

Comment: regarding point 2 i am trying to tell you that the error object reference not set to an instance of an object is due to the property name you are giving is not correct. do not merge point 1 with point 2.

Comment: I see that but what I was saying and I stand corrected is that the id_high was part of it but uninitialized when you add item.generator.contents.Add(new Items.EmbeddedGenerator()); item.generator.contents[0].id = new OnlineService.ItemId(); you see target now has the propriety but it still cant be accessed and still returns the same error